# How to pass value from JavaScript to ASP.NET C# parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I pass value from JavaScript to ASP.NET C# parameter in code below?

I have tried some methods, but I always get an empty value:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
        var concept = $(this).text();
        $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
        $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
    });
});

grid.DataSource = U.Search(//param value , txtsearch.Text);
grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: be more specific, what do want to send parameter ( or parameters or object) and how (using get or post) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the javascript value in a `<asp:hiddenfield>`, then you can access it from codebehind.